# Getting items from multiple dictionaries inside a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following piece of code based on `PythonMETAR` (some sort of weather codification in aviation) library:

```
from PythonMETAR import *
report = Metar('LRSM')
properties = report.getAttribute('cloud')
print(report)

print(properties)
```

which returns me the following result:

```
LRSM 071100Z 28005KT 220V320 9000 -RA FEW006 BKN025 BKN035 12/11 Q1010 R01/29//95

({'code': 'FEW', 'meaning': 'Few', 'oktaMin': 1, 'oktaMax': 2, 'altitude': 600, 'presenceCB': False, 'presenceTCU': False}, {'code': 'BKN', 'meaning': 'Broken', 'oktaMin': 5, 'oktaMax': 7, 'altitude': 2500, 'presenceCB': False, 'presenceTCU': False})
```

I want to create a piece of code that will look in each dictionary from the `properties` tuple and return me `TRUE` if the `code` value is either `BKN` and `OVC`. In addition to that, if `TRUE` I would like to look into the `altitude` only for `BKN` and `OVC` and check if these values are less than `1500`.

Now I'm not really afraid of the IF statements, but at the moment, after some Google searches, I'm stuck in getting those specific items out of the dictionaries and eventually connecting these items with the `altitude` values.

Comment: The expected output for the IF statement would be TRUE if the `code` value is `BKN` or `OVC` and the `altitude` values for the dictionaries that have either `BKN` or `OVC` as a `code` is less than 1500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
seq = ({'code': 'FEW', 'meaning': 'Few', 'oktaMin': 1, 'oktaMax': 2, 'altitude': 600, 'presenceCB': False, 'presenceTCU': False},
    {'code': 'BKN', 'meaning': 'Broken', 'oktaMin': 5, 'oktaMax': 7, 'altitude': 2500, 'presenceCB': False, 'presenceTCU': False})

res = [i['code'] in ('BKN', 'OVC') and i['altitude'] < 1500 for i in seq]

print(res)
```

Output

```
[False, False]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I needed!

Comment: if you dont understand what this is, look up "list comprehension" on google

Comment: Is there a way to make the code ignore this error? `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` Basically there are cases in which there are no BKN/OVC values at all, and in all of these cases it returns me a TypeError. Should I `def` a function: `if none then continue else return res`?

Comment: @instaspam what do you mean? can you paste the input for which you are getting that error?

Comment: `from PythonMETAR import *
report = Metar('LROP')
properties = report.getAttribute('cloud')
print(report)

print(properties)
res = [i['code'] in ('BKN', 'OVC') and i['altitude'] < 1500 for i in properties]

print(res)` with `LROP 071230Z 26011KT CAVOK 27/10 Q1009 NOSIG
None` as output. Basically the code doesn't find me any `cloud` dictionary to be evaluated and returns me the `TypeError` above.

Comment: in that case then what you suggested is correct, add an if check, something like `if properties is not None: res = [i['code'] in ('BKN', 'OVC') and i['altitude'] < 1500 for i in properties]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
t=({'A':'a','B':'b'}, {'A':0, 'B':'c'})

def foo(t):
    last=[]
    for d in t:
        if d['A']=='a' and d['B']=='b':
            last+=[d]
    return last

print(foo(t))
```

*foo* takes a touple and returns all the matching dicts. You can modify it to return true or a specific value of a specific thing in the *if* part.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
for dic in properties:
    if dic['code'] in ['BKN', 'OVC']:
        print(f"Dic: {dic} - TRUE, the code value is {dic['code']}") 
        if dic['altitude'] > 1500:
            print(f"  Altitude: {dic['altitude']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function called `checker()` whose input is the dictionary.

It returns two Booleans. The first Boolean indicates whether `code` is `BKN/OVC` and the second Boolean indicates the `alititude` requirement.

```py
def checker(d):
    return_booleans = [False, False]
    if d['code'] in ['BKN', 'OVC']:
        return_booleans[0] = True
        if d['altitude'] > 1500:
            return_booleans[1] = True
    return return_booleans

for d in properties:
    code_bool, altitude_bool = checker(d)
    print(code_bool, altitude_bool)
```

And the output is:

```
False False
True True
```